# Complicated SQL statement needs improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server

After asking a question on another thread about why my complex SQL statement didn't work (mostly got strange "tuples" messages), it was impressed upon me that my SQL syntax was lousy.  I readily accept that as I'm relatively new to complex SQL stuff, so I'm hoping those of you who know better than I (most of you, I'm guessing), can help me.

Here's the overall thing needed:
This is from a Property Management system which doesn't (God help me) have identity columns, but relies instead on a combination of "dept_no" (property) and "unit."  In one table resides the "rent_amoun" column (strange field names as this was previously upsized from Visual FoxPro which only allowed 10 character field names).

Then there is the "trans" table (transactions), which has every type of transaction made by everyone in every property and unit.  From that table, I need to find the "Rent Due" records for each dept_no/unit combination (in descending date order) and find the first record that is LESS than the rent amount in the first table.

I then have to take the contents of the "amt_charge" and "transcti2" (transaction_date) from the trans table and insert those values into the "oldrent" and "idate" columns of a third table (rentinc).
So I realize the SQL statement below is amateurish, but it actually worked in the Query window of SSMS, but gave me lots of problems with odbc_connect() ("tuples" errors without "SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC" in the connection string and "Ambiguous amt_charge" with it).

Here's the call:

```
SELECT x.dept_no,
       x.unit,
       x.amt_charge,
       q.rent_amoun,
       CONVERT(DATE, x.transacti2, 101) AS transacti2 
FROM (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
             t.dept_no,
             t.unit,
             t.amt_charge,
             l.rent_amoun 
      FROM (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
                   w.dept_no,
                   w.unit,
                   w.amt_charge 
            FROM trans w 
            WHERE (transacti3 = 'Rent Due') 
            GROUP BY w.dept_no,
                     w.unit,
                     w.amt_charge 
            ORDER BY w.dept_no,
                     w.unit,
                     w.amt_charge
           ) AS t 
           INNER JOIN lease_unit AS l ON t.dept_no = l.dept_no
                                AND t.unit = l.unit 
      ORDER BY t.dept_no,
               t.unit,
               t.amt_charge DESC
      ) AS q 
      INNER JOIN trans AS x ON x.dept_no = q.dept_no
                           AND x.unit = q.unit 
WHERE x.amt_charge IS NOT NULL
  AND x.transacti3 = 'Rent Due'
ORDER BY x.dept_no,
         x.unit,
         x.transacti2 DESC;
```

Comment: Whitespace and line breaks are wondering things for readability/

Comment: What other question? If it's related to the problem, include a link to that will be really helpful.

Comment: As for what you're asking here, without sample data, and expected results, I'm not sure what we can do to help you. Certainly you queries looks like you're overly complicating the problem . Why are you joining to `trans` twice here?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer, but a comment that doesn't fit in the comment section.**

When you have subqueries included in subqueries I would advise you rephrase the whole query using CTEs (Common Table Expressions). For example, your query can look like:

```
WITH
t as (
  SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    w.dept_no, 
    w.unit, 
    w.amt_charge 
  FROM trans w 
  WHERE (transacti3 = 'Rent Due') 
  GROUP BY w.dept_no, w.unit, w.amt_charge 
  ORDER BY w.dept_no, w.unit, w.amt_charge
),
q as (
  SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    t.dept_no,
    t.unit,
    t.amt_charge,
    l.rent_amoun 
  FROM t 
  INNER JOIN lease_unit AS l ON t.dept_no = l.dept_no AND t.unit = l.unit 
  ORDER BY t.dept_no, t.unit, t.amt_charge DESC
)
SELECT x.dept_no,
       x.unit,
       x.amt_charge,
       q.rent_amoun,
       CONVERT(DATE, x.transacti2, 101) AS transacti2 
FROM q 
INNER JOIN trans AS x ON x.dept_no = q.dept_no AND x.unit = q.unit 
WHERE x.amt_charge IS NOT NULL
  AND x.transacti3 = 'Rent Due'
ORDER BY x.dept_no, x.unit, x.transacti2 DESC
```

This way you can test the subqueries first to check they are doing the right thing. For example, to check `q`:

```
WITH
t as (
  SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    w.dept_no, 
    w.unit, 
    w.amt_charge 
  FROM trans w 
  WHERE (transacti3 = 'Rent Due') 
  GROUP BY w.dept_no, w.unit, w.amt_charge 
  ORDER BY w.dept_no, w.unit, w.amt_charge
),
q as (
  SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    t.dept_no,
    t.unit,
    t.amt_charge,
    l.rent_amoun 
  FROM t 
  INNER JOIN lease_unit AS l ON t.dept_no = l.dept_no AND t.unit = l.unit 
  ORDER BY t.dept_no, t.unit, t.amt_charge DESC
)
select * from q -- this line queries q. Or you can check t here...
```

Check each part is doing the right thing, by using the last `SELECT`. Then you can test the whole thing.

Comment: You can even do `select * from q; return; select x.dept_no ...`.  It will still work.  This way you don't have to worry about omitting or commenting out the final sql statement as you do these checks.